# Data backup about DashDB and Cloudant

Tags: ibm-cloud

In IBM official document it shows there are some replicators for DashDB and Cloudant in cloud. I wonder whether there is any data recovery service for our application automatically without additional cost. Please reply kindly.

Comment: Do you mean replication between Db2 Warehouse on Cloud (former dashDB) and Cloudant or just any form of HA backup? There are daily backups for all service plans.

Answer (score 0):

There are daily backup for DashDB in cloud, and for cloudant DB I use replication to do backup.